# "if I had known it WERE you, I might not have attended your phone." OR "if I had known it WAS you, I might not have attended your phone"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, subjunctives

Can somebody tell me which  one is correct because I think the "was" one is right because here, in the sentence, there is no hypothetical situation or something related to subjunctive mood probably present.

Comment: It's ***was*** in your context (the "embedded" finite clause shouldn't use subjunctive mood). The subjunctive here would be *If **I would have** known it was you...* - more usually contracted to *If **I'd have** known it was you...* ("unpacked" by me into *If I **had** have known...,* but many grammarians will take issue with me on that).

Comment: @FumbleFingers None of that addresses OP's question in the slightest.

Comment: @BadZen: I suggest the *exact* reason for the OP generating an invalid utterance above is specifically because s/he doesn't understand how and when to use the subjunctive mode.

Comment: Both are wrong. Try:  If I had known it was you, I might not have answered your phone call.

Comment: 'attended your phone' is the most suspect part of this sentence. You can attend a class, but how do you attend a phone?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

People argue about this one a lot.  Both are acceptable and in use.

Singular, 1st or 3rd person:
"**I was here.**"
"**He was here.**"

Plural, or 2nd person:
"**They were here.**"
"**You were here.**"

However, the verb form can be set by "it" in your example.

"**It was you all along!**"
"**If I had known it was you...**"  (*it was*)

...or it can be set by "you".

"**If I had known it were you...**"  (*you were*)

"It were you all along!" is incorrect.

By the way, "attend" and "phone" do not colocate like that.  One cannot "attend" a "phone."  You may mean "If I had known it were you, I would not have **answered your phone call**.

Comment: Please explain your downvote.

Comment: It's my downvote, because (deliberately or accidentally, I can't tell) you give the impression ***If I had known it were you...*** is valid English.

Comment: Please review https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences-was-instead-of-were/.   Also perhaps do a corpus search, since you seem fond of that.

Comment: You've misunderstood the text in my comment under the question, and you've misunderstood how to apply the principles in your link to the OP's example (where the subjunctive *could in principle* be applied to initial ***If I had known = If I would have known = If I were to have known***). You can't validly apply the subjunctive mode to the embedded clause *that might have been but **wasn't** known*).

Comment: It's "subjunctive mood", not "mode".    "If you were here, you would have known what to do!"   By your argument, was the listener possibly "here"?  Or is this incorrect use?   Of course the answer is "neither"; you've invented this grammar "rule" out of whole cloth.   Or - cite a source.  (Really, do a corpus search, "If I had known it were you" is certainly in common use, despite this prattle.)

Comment: Of course it's not "in common use"! Have a look at [this usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+known+it+were%2Chad+known+it+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Where if you check the actual instances of the "flatlining" usage you'll find they're all irrelevant "false positive" matches, such as *Those who **had known it were** Joseph, Zacharias, and Elisabeth; and all these were dead.* And *There was something wrong in that chest , and had been for a long time, and they **had known it. Were** they not warned...?*

Comment: This is likely pointless but let's try anyway.   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%2C+apple&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

I conclude that the word apple is not in common use.   What is my error?

Comment: You know perfectly well what your error is there. All your chart shows is that ***the*** is far more common than ***apple*** (which you knew already, so that's why you chose to compare those two words). I'll admit I can't force all matches in *my* chart to be "hypothetical irrealis" ***If I** had known it were/was* because NGrams has a 5 word limit. But you can certainly compare the results from "If I had known it were/was" in Google Books, which should make it obvious which version is more common.

Comment: You point out my error, then double down on your exact same one:  to wit, being less common does not make it ungrammatical, or demonstrate that it is not in common use.  This is wildly off topic now, Please avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147532/discussion-between-badzen-and-fumblefingers).

Answer (score 0):

You must use "was" in the embedded clause.

In the conditional clause it is possible to use an irrealis form "were":

> If he were happy ...

But in a subordinate clause the normal agreement rules apply.

> If she had known he was happy.

The clause "he was happy" is completing the clause "she had known ..." It isn't directly subordinated by "if".